# How to write an own emulator?

Tags: security, emulation, sandbox, antivirus

I want to write an own emulator(sandbox) in windows for my antivirus
It 's just a simple emulator to test the system change went execute a file(.exe dll ...)
But i dont know where i should start,i know a litle asm and c/c++
Can help me ?

Thanks !